# Why am I getting undefined?

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the following code and I'm trying to modify the html of some table data. However, the value of `$(this).html()` seems to always be undefined. I don't understand why. Could someone explain please.

```
$(document).on('click',"td",function() { 
        //console.log($(this).html());
    }).focusout(function(){
        console.log($(this).html()); //undifined 
});
```

Comment: I thought Sheldon never asked for explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding an event to the document, then getting it's html. The document doesn't have html.

What you probably want is this:

```
$(document).on('click',"td",function() { 
    //console.log($(this).html());
}).on('blur','td',function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); //not undifined  :-)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
$('td').on('click', function () {
}).focusout(function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); //undifined 
});
```

Your scope may be limited with your current selector.